# Testclass for a printview

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, string

I found an example of a class how to set the printview of a word document. I would like to write a testclass for this. What wil I be testing in this case do I do a assert on the string? See my example below:

```
public class PrintViewMSWord{
    public PrintViewMSWord(ApexPages.StandardController acon) { }

public String getPrintView()
{
    return
    '<!--[if gte mso 9]>' +
        '<xml>' +
        '<w:WordDocument>' +
        '<w:View>Print</w:View>' +
        '<w:Zoom>100</w:Zoom>' +
        '<w:DoNotOptimizeForBrowser/>' +
        '</w:WordDocument>' +
        '</xml>' +
        '<![endif]>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Contact data also and put acon like this using santanu code

```
        static testMethod void testPrintView()
  {
         Contact acon = new Contact(lastname = 'test');
         insert acon;
//create pageReference
PageReference page = Page.MyVFP;
Test.setCurrentPage(page);

//pass parameter to the page
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id',acon.Id);

//create an instance of controller.
ApexPages.StandardController standrdcontroller = new ApexPages.StandardController(acon);
PrintViewMSWord myController = new PrintViewMSWord(standrdcontroller);

String strPrintView = myController.getPrintView();
Boolean result = strPrintView.contains('<w:View>Print</w:View>');
System.assertEquals(result, true);

//do the same for other values.
```

}

Comment: @santanu  dint know that acom was abbreviation for a contact.   'PageReference pageRef = Page.MyVFP;
Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);'   Please update answer cloudZigZag

Answer (score 1):

You need to extract the value and verify those values as below:

```
static testMethod void testPrintView()
{
    //create pageReference
    PageReference page = Page.MyVFP;
    Test.setCurrentPage(page);

    //pass parameter to the page
    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id',acon.Id);

    //create an instance of controller.
    ApexPages.StandardController standrdcontroller = new ApexPages.StandardController(acon);
    PrintViewMSWord myController = new PrintViewMSWord(standrdcontroller);

    String strPrintView = myController.getPrintView();
    Boolean result = strPrintView.contains('<w:View>Print</w:View>');
    System.assertEquals(result, true);

    //do the same for other values.
}
```

Comment: I tested this but get the error: Variable does not exist: acon

Comment: firstly insert acon (StandardController) data(whatever your standardcontroller like account,contact etc). I think @jenssen you haven't post  full code here!

Comment: @cloudZigZag  Besides the controller I have the following VFP: '<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="PrintViewMSWord" showHeader="false"  contentType="application/msword#ducumument.doc" cache="true" >
    <html xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word">
   
        <head>
            <style>
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
....
    </body>
    </html>

</apex:page>'

Comment: @Jenssen, next time onward when you post a question, give a try and specify where you are facing issues. We cannot write entire test class for your purpose